# how to send raw http header

Tags: python, http, twisted, python-requests

For some reasons, I want to send raw http header to server, can python **requests** do that? For example, http header like this,

```
GET http://baidu.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: baidu.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

I find **twisted** may do this, but it's a little complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `twisted`:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers

agent = Agent(reactor)

d = agent.request(
    'GET',
    'http://baidu.com/',
    Headers({
            'User-Agent': ['Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0'],
            'Accept': ['text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'],
            'Accept-Language': ['en-US,en;q=0.5'],
            'Accept-Encoding': ['gzip, deflate'],
            'Connection': ['keep-alive']
        }),
    None)

def Response(null):
    print('Response received')

def Shutdown(null):
    print('Shutting down the reactor now')
    reactor.stop()

d.addCallback(Response)     # exec Response() after request is rcvd
d.addBoth(Shutdown)         # shut down after response rcvd
reactor.run()
```

It is more complicated (especially if you want to "do stuff" with the response), but `twisted` is something you should know if you plan to do web or concurrent programming in Python. Hope this helps you, if not I hope that it helps someone struggling with HTTP headers and `twisted`.

## Edit - March 7, 2016

Using `treq`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from treq import get
from twisted.internet.task import react


def handleResponse(response):
    """ Callback Function

    Once the response is recived, display the information. 
    This is the part where I suspect people will have the most
    trouble wrapping their heads around since it's heavily 
    dependent on deferreds (ie. futures or promises).
    """
    print('Code: %s\n' % response.code)

    print('Simple print:')
    response.content().addCallback(print)       # simple way to print on py2 & py3

    text = response.text()                      # returns a deferred
    text.addCallback(displayText)               # the way you should be handling responses, ie. via callbacks

def displayText(text):
    """ Callback Function

    Simply display the text. You would usually do more useful
    things in this call back, such as maniuplating the response 
    text or setting the text to some global or otherwise accessible
    variable(s).
    """
    print('Deferred print:')
    print(text)

def main(reactor):
    """
    This is the main function which will execute a request using the 
    GET method. After getting the response, the response code and content
    will be displayed. Finally, the twisted reactor will stop (since 
    the react function is being used).
    """
    url = 'http://baidu.com/'
    header={
        'User-Agent': ['Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0'],
        'Accept': ['text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'],
        'Accept-Language': ['en-US,en;q=0.5'],
        'Accept-Encoding': ['gzip, deflate'],
        'Connection': ['keep-alive']}

    d = get(url, headers=header)
    d.addCallback(handleResponse)
    return d


react(main)         # run the main function and display results
```

The `treq` package is much easier to use than using `twisted` outright and it shares many of the features and syntax of `requests`.

## References

- [How to create web client using Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html) - It's best to learn the basics of `twisted` first before or immediately after reading this tutorial.
- [treq on github](https://github.com/twisted/treq)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
import requests    

headers = {'Host': 'baidu.com',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0,'
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

requests.get('http://baidu.com/', headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `requests.request` method (and all its derivatives like `request.get` or `request.head`) can be passed a `headers` parameter. See the documentation for [request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request) and for [custom headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers).

You can use it like

```
requests.get('http://baidu.com', headers={'Host':'baidu.com',
                                          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                                          ...})
```